# Call Jasper file from service

Tags: java, spring, pdf

I am new with Jasper stuff, I want to try to generate pdf file with jasper from my application.
This is the scenario :

I have one file (reportEmployee.jrxml) that I have built in iReport, in my application, I have one link, and if we click that link, my application will create the the report in pdf file and save it to my local storage.

I have tried for excel and word and it works, only pdf that I feel confuse to do it.

This is the code
1. on jsp file

```
<td><a href="<c:url value ="/savepdf"/>">Save to PDF</a></td>
<td><a href="<c:url value = "/save"/>">Save to Excel</a></td>
<td><a href="<c:url value = "/saveword"/>">Save to Word</a></td>
```

2. the Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/savepdf")
public String dataEmployeePdf()
{
    employeeManager.dataEmployeePDFDownload();
    return "employ/editEmployeeList";
}
```

3. on EmployeeManagerImpl (implementation of EmployeeManager)

```
@Override
public void dataEmployeePDFDownload() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try
    {

        File file = new File("report/reportEmployee.jrxml"); 
        String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(absolutePath));
        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(input);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null);
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);
    }
    catch(JRException ex)
    {
        ex.getMessage();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I do not need to send data from database through my application, because I have made that file (employeeReport.jrxml) to get data from database automaticaly.
It same case with save to word and save to excel, when we click that link, it will write file to local storage like this

[image]

anyone can help me? I hope I didn't repost about this
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download the file you have to pass the content to the `response.getOutputStream()`. you can set other info to the response like  header info for setting fileName, enconding etc.  or set the file contentType.

```
 @RequestMapping("/savepdf")
    public void dataEmployeePdf(HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {

            File file = new File("report/reportEmployee.jrxml");
            String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(absolutePath));
            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(input);
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null);
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint,response.getOutputStream());
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            ex.getMessage();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: allow me to try it, mate, but what HttpServletResponse that will be send to this method?

Comment: it's spring that inject the response to the methode